# What is the equivalent of IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY on linux?

Tags: c, linux, windows, driver

I am trying to get the hard drives serial number on linux without the need for root access. This is possible on windows via [this source](http://www.winsim.com/diskid32/diskid32.cpp) In essence it does an `DeviceIoControl` with `IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY`. What is the ioctl version?

Comment: You may need to be root to get that information, whatever the way you get it. And it might not exist (e.g. in a `chroot`-ed environment or a VM, or on a diskless machine with NFS filesystem like many virtual internet servers have). You could `strace` the linux command displaying that information... (`hdparm`, `fdisk`) to find out the syscalls involved in getting it.

Comment: Look into the source code of `hdparm` since with `-i` it is retrieving what you want. But it needs to be root for that (probably to do some `ioctl` with `SG_IO`). So you won't be able to retrieve that information without being root.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch thanks, but the whole point was to get the info without needing root permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can ask udev, without needing root permissions. Try this command and note the ID_SERIAL line:

```sh
/sbin/udevadm info --query=property --name /dev/sda
```

Programatically you'd use libudev.

Comment: is this a wrapper around sysfs? or is it the logic behind sysfs?

Comment: As far as I know, sysfs doesn't have this information. udev gets this by interrogating the drive itself (see the code in udev's `ata-id.c`). But that would need root, which you don't have.